# Print a variable with index (eg. x_1)

Tags: string, printf, maxima

i am trying to print variables with indices.
The goal is to write something like:

> x_1 + x_2 = 3 + 1 = 4

The problem is, that variables just like x_1 does not show an index. It shows the underscore itself.

```
/* works fine */    
print(x_1)$ 
x_1;

/* Does not work */
ostream: make_string_output_stream()$
printf(ostream, string(x_1))$
get_output_stream_string(ostream);
```

[Output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49NkF.png)

Converting "x_1" into a string destroys the underscore, but you need a string for the method printf().

Are there workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What to do here probably depends somewhat on what goal you need to achieve with this. Can you say more about the larger goal you are working toward?

In order to generate output which has typesetting instructions in it, you can call the `tex` or `tex1` function to generate TeX output. If that needs to be displayed in a web page, I believe you can make use of the MathJax Javascript library. Sorry, I don't know more about MathJax.

You should probably write `x[1]` instead of `x_1`. Displaying `x_1` with a subscript `1` is a convenience -- the rest of Maxima doesn't know much about it.

EDIT: There is also an add-on package to output MathML; there might be two such packages, I would have to check. If MathML could help solve your problem, I will look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the index notation. MathML solved my problem! Thanks !